# Can "father" be used as "Dad"?

Tags: possessives, capitalization

As "Dad" and "Mom" start with a capital letter if they came as the father and mother's names. Then, is it possible for "father" to be used in the same situation but without capitalizing its first letter?

For example:

> How is **father's** current health?

I think it is possible to write it:

> How is **Dad's** current health?

and

> How is **my father's** current health?

But I *remember* hearing it in the structure of the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't tend to use "father" as a proper noun in this way.  When Dad is used as a proper noun in place of someone's name it is always being used to one's own father. Using the formal term "Father" as a proper noun sounds stilted and stiff. It seems like inappropriate formality.

Learners will rarely need to use "Dad" as a proper noun, and will never need to use "Father" like this. It is possible to say "How is Father's health" (capitalised) but a context in which you should say this will rarely arise.

If you were speaking to the doctor you might say "How is my father's health"?  If you were speaking to your sister you might say "How is Dad?", although an English Learner would not usually speak to their own sister in a foreign language. If you were writing an upper-class character from the 1920s, you might have that character say "How is Father?"

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer! According to your explanation, I would say it may be suitable if the speaker was in a very serious, big conflict with her father, right?

Comment: Perhaps. It sounds emotionally cold.

Comment: Use of "Father" and "Mother" as proper nouns when addressing or discussing one's parents is regarded as severely old-fashioned, bordering on archaic. I, born 1952 (UK), called my father "Dad", but he, born 1920, called his parents "Father" and "Mother". My father was an exceptionally formal person.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey _ Thank you for sharing this information, but what would be the alternative for the speaker's situation then?

Comment: In writing my father, and others like him, would have capitalised thus: Dear Mother, I hope you are well and that Father is too".

Comment: Richmal Crompton's character, William Brown, addresses his father as "Father": His father was sitting in an armchair by the window reading the evening paper. “Father,” said William suddenly, “s’pose I came to you an’ said you was to give me a hundred pounds an’ I’d give you five pounds next year an’ so on, would you give it me?”